# How does the pressurized suspension of the Hyperloop not affect the tube pressure?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, transportation, drag

So one of the proposed suspension systems that will be used on the [hyperloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperloop) include the externally pressurized air cushions. These cushions lift (or at least help lift) the capsule and reduce drag when the capsule is in motion. Also, the tube itself is supposed to have a very low pressure. But won't 100s of capsules moving in the tube releasing significant amounts of compressed air pressurize the tube and thereby significantly increase drag? I suppose this could be solved by perpetually depressurizing the tube, but I did not see any information on it. Does anyone know how this problem was addressed or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The air used for the air cushions will come from the air still in the tube pressurized by the pod itself.

Thus the system remains closed (all air that is released is sucked out of the environment).

Comment: Ah, I see. That's pretty neat.

Comment: slightly related and currently unanswered: [Does the Hyperloop One suspension require constant current through copper windings?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/22285/6264)